# How to group lines in a Bokeh table?

Tags: python, bokeh, bokehjs

To create a Bokeh table with *selectable* lines, I'm using this [example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/wiki/Filterable-Data-Source).
The issue is that my data is represented as groups of different lines that looks like this:

[image]

Any idea how it can be done in Bokeh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in `DataTable` does not support anything like this. It is possible to extend Bokeh, so you could consider [creating a custom extension](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html), that wraps some other JavaScript table library for use with Bokeh.